# Swap Hard Disks

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, efi

Is it in principle possible to swipe the hard disk out of a MacBook, swipe a new (blank) hard disk in, install the OS on the new disk, then swipe the old disk back in and find the machine operational again?

I would like to tinker with a new hard disk (bootcamp and perhaps rEFIt), but if that fails, I'd like to continue from the installation I have right now.

**Edit** Clearly, the hard disk will be unchanged. My question is whether the process of installing OS X / bootcamp will change something (SMC, PRAM, ...?) that makes the machine incompatible with the previous installation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, certainly. Removing the original drive will leave it exactly as it was before.

Comment: It's clear that nothing can change on the hard disk while it's disconnected. I have now clarified the question.

Comment: I know a guy whose double boot was in fact a double drive. One for Windows, one for the Mac OS. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Did this involve removing the internal drive every time, or could he reboot into the other OS without using a screwdriver (a KVM-style switch for SATA perhaps..?) ?

Comment: Nope. He needed to remove 2 screws (Old Macbook) to change the HD. So it's not a very convinient solution but I works.

Answer (score 1):

On the first boot after changing a drive it may take an extra couple of seconds for the new boot destination to be written to the PRAM, but it won't cause any issues.